# PowerShell script to click a JavaScript Button

Tags: javascript, powershell

I'm currently working on a PowerShell script to launch a page and click a button. The button is a JavaScript Button with no << a >> tag. Both variants return You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression. I'm sure I'm circling the answer but I'm still in a holding pattern. Thanks in advance!

```
    $ie = new-object -com internetexplorer.application
    $ie.visible=$true
    $ie.navigate('http://192.168.63.10/counters/usage.php')
    while($ie.busy) {sleep 1}

    $link = @($ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('button')) | Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Download File to Your Computer'}
    $link.click()
```

I've also tried:

```
 $link2 =   $ie.Document.documentElement.getElementsByClassName('horizButtonBarAboveTableLeft')| Where-Object {$_.innerText -eq 'Download File to Your Computer'}
$link2.click()
```

Here is the HTML (looking to click the button with GenerateCsvFile():)

```
<div class="horizButtonBarAboveTableLeft">
<button onclick="document.location=document.URL">
    <img src="/images/counters/refresh_renew_32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32">
    Refresh    </button>

<img src="/images/ClearGIF.gif" width="19" height="20" alt="">

<button onclick="GenerateCsvFile();">
    <img src="/images/counters/download_import_32.png" alt="" width="32" height="32">
    Download File to Your Computer    </button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Where-Object clause fails because there is additional whitespace in the innerText which causes the equality condition to fail.  Thus the `$link` variable is null. This then causes the `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression` error.  Try trimming the whitespace.

```
Where-Object { $_.innerText.Trim() -eq 'Download File to Your Computer' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately even with the Trim function it still returns a null. I'm wondering if $ie.Document.getElementsByTagName('button') is causing the issue.

Comment: Looks like the issue is related to Windows 10 and PS 5. I've found several threads with similar issues. I never considered it since the error didn't really point in that directions. Boo!

Comment: I'm assuming the issue is with the InternetExplorer com object.

Comment: Yes, that's the issue. I've since tackled the task another way using Invoke-Webrequest which is working well.